# R: forcing an internal method to use a function from another package

Tags: r

I am writing a package that uses `getModel` from flexmix in one of my functions.

The problem lies in which of the BIC/AIC functions it uses (from the stats package).

```
> getMethod("getModel","stepFlexmix")
Method Definition:

function (object, ...) 
{
    .local <- function (object, which = "BIC") 
    {
        if (which == "AIC") 
            which <- which.min(sapply(object@models, function(x) AIC(x)))
        if (which == "BIC") 
            which <- which.min(sapply(object@models, function(x) BIC(x)))
        if (which == "ICL") 
            which <- which.min(sapply(object@models, function(x) ICL(x)))
        object@models[[which]]
    }
    .local(object, ...)
}
<environment: namespace:flexmix>

Signatures:
        object       
target  "stepFlexmix"
defined "stepFlexmix"
```

In another function, I have used BIC from the flowMerge package, where in the header I have:

```
@' importFrom flowMerge BIC
```

The problem is that the getModel function now uses the BIC from flowMerge instead of stats. I suspect it is in the definition of the namespace? I'm not too sure.

And since it is called internally, I do not have the option of doing

```
stats::BIC
```

Is there an elegant way of doing this within a package? It all works fine and dandy if I just ran functions on their own.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by

1. Removing `@' importFrom flowMerge BIC`, thus removing the call in `NAMESPACE`
2. calling `flowMerge::BIC`

This would make `getMethod` use the `BIC` from `stats`. It is a workaround, probably not the best way.